# ServiceBroker : Stored procedure working as stand-alone but not as trigger

Tags: sql, service-broker, altova

We are trying to launch webservices asynchronously from SQL Server and Service Broker seemed the most interesting choice.

For Service Broker itself many different examples can be found online.  I managed to have a working example in which I sent several parameters in a message on a queue and have the queue trigger automatically when a message arrives on it.
The problem is that the code works fine when I just save the information to another table but it fails when I try to call a webservice.  It then has the effect of stopping the queue.
It still works when I run the stored procedure by itself but not as a trigger on the queue.
Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong please?

My Stored Procedure for getting the message from the queue is as follows :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CommandLauncher
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @RecvReqDlgHandle AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @RecvReqMsg AS nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @RecvReqMsgName AS sysname;
    DECLARE @xmlBody xml;
    DECLARE @MsgId int;
    DECLARE @ChannelType varchar(30);
    DECLARE @JobUrl varchar(50);
    DECLARE @LocalPath varchar(100);
    SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;

    WHILE (1 = 1)
         BEGIN
             BEGIN TRANSACTION;
             WAITFOR(
             RECEIVE TOP (1) @RecvReqDlgHandle = conversation_handle,
                             @RecvReqMsg = message_body,
                             @RecvReqMsgName = message_type_name
                             FROM MessageQueue), TIMEOUT 5000;
             IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
                 BEGIN
                     ROLLBACK;
                     BREAK;
                 END
             IF @RecvReqMsgName = N'AltovaWebRequests'
                 BEGIN
                    select @xmlBody = CAST(@RecvReqMsg as xml);
                    select @MsgId = @xmlBody.value('(//WebRequest/MsgId)[1]', 'int');
                    select @ChannelType = @xmlBody.value('(//WebRequest/ChannelType)[1]', 'varchar(30)');
                    select @FlowForceJobUrl = @xmlBody.value('(//WebRequest/JobUrl)[1]', 'varchar(50)');
                    select @LocalPath = @xmlBody.value('(//WebRequest/LocalPath)[1]', 'varchar(100)');
                    -- The following command always works fine
                    insert into ResultTable (MsgId, ChannelType, FlowForceJobUrl, LocalPath, [Conversation], DateTimeInserted) 
                        values (@MsgId, @ChannelType, @FlowForceJobUrl, @LocalPath, @RecvReqDlgHandle, getdate())
                    -- It stops functioning when I call the webservice
                    exec [spLaunchWebService_Test] @MsgId, @ChannelType, @JobUrl, @LocalPath
                 END
             ELSE
                 IF @RecvReqMsgName = N'<a class="linkclass" href="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog">http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog</a>'
                     BEGIN
                         END CONVERSATION @RecvReqDlgHandle;
                     END
                 ELSE
                     IF @RecvReqMsgName = N'<a class="linkclass" href="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error">http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error</a>'
                         BEGIN
                             END CONVERSATION @RecvReqDlgHandle;
                         END
             COMMIT TRANSACTION;
         END
END

The procedure spLaunchWebService_Test sets several parameters and calls a webservice
The Stored Procedure for calling a webservice can also be easily found online but I use this one :


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spHTTPRequest]
    @URI varchar(2000) = 'http://000.000.000.000/service/',     
    @methodName varchar(50) = 'Get',
    @requestBody varchar(8000) = '',
    @SoapAction varchar(255),
    @UserName nvarchar(100), -- Domain\UserName or UserName
    @Password nvarchar(100),
    @responseText varchar(8000) output
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF @methodName = ''
BEGIN
    select FailPoint = 'Method Name must be set'
    return
END
set @responseText = 'FAILED'
DECLARE @objectID int
DECLARE @hResult int
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255)
EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objectID OUT
IF @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
    SELECT hResult = @hResult,
            description = @desc,
            MedthodName = @methodName
    goto destroy
    return
END
-- open the destination URI with Specified method
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false', @UserName, @Password
IF @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT     hResult = @hResult,
            description = @desc,
            MedthodName = @methodName
      goto destroy
      return
END
-- set request headers
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
IF @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = @hResult,
            description = @desc,
            MedthodName = @methodName
      goto destroy
      return
END
-- set soap action
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'SOAPAction', @SoapAction
IF @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = @hResult,
            description = @desc,
            MedthodName = @methodName
      goto destroy
      return
END
declare @len int
set @len = len(@requestBody)
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
IF @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT     hResult = @hResult,
            description = @desc,
            MedthodName = @methodName
      goto destroy
      return
END

-- send the request
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, @requestBody
IF    @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = @hResult,
            description = @desc,
            MedthodName = @methodName
      goto destroy
      return
END
declare @statusText varchar(1000), @status varchar(1000)
-- Get status text
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'StatusText', @statusText out
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'Status', @status out
select @status, @statusText, @methodName
-- Get response text
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText', @responseText out
IF @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = @hResult,
            description = @desc,
            MedthodName = @methodName
      goto destroy
      return
END
destroy:
      exec sp_OADestroy @objectID
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems our issue is resolved ;
Had to set "SET TRUSTWORTHY ON " in the database were the servicebroker is running.